# Concatenating Multiple Rows Over Same ID in SQL

Tags: sql, concatenation, coalesce

I'm trying to concatenate multiple rows on the basis of same `OrderID` for a particular person. The goal is to achieve a row that contains the total order of each specific `OrderID`.

I have a data from a query as follows:

[image]
What I need is to concatenate the particulars on basis of same `OrderID`.

Result should be:

```
PartyName   | partyCode | OrderID | particulars                                  | Price | Total

Fine Mark   | 3         | 5069    | suji50kg/1500/2,maida50kg/1/2,suji50kg/1500/3| 7802  | 19432
```

What I have done:

```
SELECT 
    @col = COALESCE(@col, ' ') + ' , ' + particulars 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.orderID,
        CONCAT(a.item, '/', a.unitPrice, '/', a.quantity) as particulars 
    FROM tblOrderDetails a, tblAddParty b, tblPartyOrder c 
    WHERE a.orderID = c.orderID 
        AND b.partyID = c.partyID 
        AND b.partyName = 'Fine Marketing Islamabad'
        AND c.date >= '2014-03-06' 
        AND c.date <= '2016-03-25') mine

SELECT 
    date, 
    partyName, 
    partyCode, 
    orderID, 
    @col as Particulars, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN total > credit THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS debit,
    MIN(CASE WHEN total < credit THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS credit,
    MIN(credit) + SUM(totalprice) AS balance 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        c.date, 
        b.partyName, 
        b.partyCode,
        a.orderID, 
        CONCAT(a.item, '/', a.unitPrice, '/', a.quantity) AS particulars,
        a.totalprice,  
        c.credit, 
        c.total,
        c.price 
    FROM tblOrderDetails a, tblAddParty b, tblPartyOrder c 
    WHERE a.orderID = c.orderID  
        AND b.partyID = c.partyID 
        AND b.partyName = 'Fine Marketing Islamabad' 
        AND c.date >= '2014-03-06' 
        AND c.date <= '2016-03-25') marked 
GROUP BY 
    partyName, 
    partyCode, 
    orderID, 
    date 
ORDER BY date
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Please make some attempt at formatting your queries (hint:  four spaces in the front formats the text).

Comment: ok.. any idea how to solve it ? will appreciate greatly.

Comment: You need to use an aggregation function, e.g. array_agg() in postgres or group_concat() in bigquery.